# Passing data to the dynamic click handler when using the ReactJS Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code structure:

```
export const DropUp = (props) => {

    const [menuItemState, setMenuItemState] = useState(props.menuItems);

    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);

    const onClick = () => setIsActive(!isActive);

    return (
        <div className="menu-container">
            <nav className={`menu ${isActive ? "active" : "inactive"}`}>
                <ul>
                    {
                        menuItemState.map((eachItem, key) => {
                            return <li onClick={eachItem.clickHandler} key={key}>{eachItem.menuName}</li>
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I am using the above component in my demo class:

```
import React, { Component }     from 'react';
import DropUp   from './dropup';


class Demo extends Component {

constructor() {

    this.menuItemsTools = [
            {menuID: 101, menuName: "Tools 1", clickHandler: this.showTools.bind(this)},
            {menuID: 102, menuName: "Tools 2", clickHandler: this.showTools.bind(this)},
            {menuID: 103, menuName: "Tools 3", clickHandler: this.showTools.bind(this)},
        ];
}


showTools(item) {
        console.log(item)
}

render() {

        return (
            <div>
        <div >
            <DropUp buttonText={"Tools"} menuItems={this.menuItemsTools} />
        </div>
        </div>
    );

}

}
```

Is it possible to pass the menu ID when clicking a menu item, using the clickHandler ?

Something like:
`eachItem.clickHandler(eachItem.menuID)`

That means, when I click a menu item,  I want to display 101 or 102 or 103 in the browser console.

Can anyone please help to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. You're actually also really close with your suggestion. The only thing that you need to change is to make it a callback function. Meaning it would be:

```
() => eachItem.clickHandler(eachItem.menuID)
```